# UiNavigationController Autorotation not Working on Device?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, nsnotifications, autorotate

Why is UINavigationController AutoRotation not working on the Device? How can I set auto Rotation property for UinavigationController?

```
    **BusinessCardAppDelegate.m**

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    { 
           [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];  
        RootView *rView=[[RootView alloc]initWithNibName:@"RootView" bundle:nil];
        self.naviGationController =[[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rView]autorelease];

        [self.window addSubview:naviGationController.view];
        return YES;
    }

    **RootView.m**

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.title =@"BusinessCard";  
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationFunction:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

    }

    -(void)orientationFunction:(NSNotification*)notification
    {
        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
         switch (orientation)
        {
            case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
                /* AlertView Show*/
                break;

            case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
               /* AlertView Show*/
                break;
            case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
               /* AlertView Show*/
                break;
            case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
               /* AlertView Show*/
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

  }

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

Why this is not working on device, but working fine in simulator? I didn't understand why this is not working?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` returns UIDeviceOrientation, not UIInterfaceOrientation.

If you want to get your current interface orientation you can use follow:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
```

or

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = self.interfaceOrientation; // into UIViewController
```